# tabular, how to align in this case?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I align first column to the left, other two columns to the right?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} | p{2cm} | p{2.5cm}}
\hline
$ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I $       & 64   & 0   \\ 
$ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I \, I $  & 358  & 31  \\
$ 3 \, I \, I $            & 21   & 0  \\
$ 3 \, 3 \, I \, I $       & 356  & 46  \\
$ 3 \, 2 \, 2 \, I \, I$   & 7344 & 23046 \\
$ 2 \, 2 \, 3 \, I \, I$   & 1308 & 359 \\
$ 4 \, 4 \, I \, I     $   & 3522 & 7983 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

I tried `r` after `p{2cm}`, but it vertical line is removed. I want to keep vertical lines, just want to align last two columns to the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `array` package you can add `>{\raggedleft}` in front of `p{2cm}` to align contents of column to the right

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} |>{\raggedleft} p{2cm} |>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{2.5cm}}
        \hline
        $ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I $       & 64   & 0   \\ 
        $ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I \, I $  & 358  & 31  \\
        $ 3 \, I \, I $            & 21   & 0  \\
        $ 3 \, 3 \, I \, I $       & 356  & 46  \\
        $ 3 \, 2 \, 2 \, I \, I$   & 7344 & 23046 \\
        $ 2 \, 2 \, 3 \, I \, I$   & 1308 & 359 \\
        $ 4 \, 4 \, I \, I     $   & 3522 & 7983 \\
        \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: somehow I got error. seems clashed with other packages

Answer (score 2):

You can get better results with `siunitx`, when numeric tables are concerned.

I also added a trick for simplifying the input, using `collcell` and a suitable macro for splitting the input at spaces and deliver it separated by `\,`.

I removed the vertical rules and used `booktabs` horizontal rules; you can reinsert them if you really want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,siunitx,booktabs,collcell}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\alimleft}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  $\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \, }$
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  >{\collectcell\alimleft}l<{\endcollectcell}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=5.0,group-digits=false]
}
\toprule
2 2 I I   &   64 &     0 \\ 
2 2 I I I &  358 &    31 \\
3 I I     &   21 &     0 \\
3 3 I I   &  356 &    46 \\
3 2 2 I I & 7344 & 23046 \\
2 2 3 I I & 1308 &   359 \\
4 4 I I   & 3522 &  7983 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

There's no need to use the `\alimleft` trick (use a more sensible macro name). Also

```
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=5.0,group-digits=false]
}
\toprule
$ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I $       & 64   & 0   \\ 
$ 2 \, 2 \, I \, I \, I $  & 358  & 31  \\
$ 3 \, I \, I $            & 21   & 0  \\
$ 3 \, 3 \, I \, I $       & 356  & 46  \\
$ 3 \, 2 \, 2 \, I \, I$   & 7344 & 23046 \\
$ 2 \, 2 \, 3 \, I \, I$   & 1308 & 359 \\
$ 4 \, 4 \, I \, I     $   & 3522 & 7983 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
```

would give the same result.

[image]